# Select2 get value from server

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.org/) for a multiselect field, and I get the options from server, I can store them in DB, but I am not sure how can I display the selected options if I already have some value in DB.

```
            <select name="multipleSelect2[]" class="multipleSelect2" multiple="true">
                <?php foreach ($modality_list as $term) { ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></option> 
                <?php } ?>
            </select> 

            <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".multipleSelect2").select2({
                        placeholder: "select modalities.." //placeholder
                    });
                })
            </script>
```

**dd for options**

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 38
            [name] => Biofield Tuning
            [slug] => biofield-tuning
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 38
            [taxonomy] => product_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 92
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 80
            [name] => Breathwork
            [slug] => breathwork
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 80
            [taxonomy] => product_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 92
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )
) ....
```

**Selected values from DB**

```
["38","80"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way. IF the value exists then selected is true.

```
<select name="multipleSelect2[]" class="multipleSelect2" multiple="true">
    <?php foreach ($modality_list as $term) {
      if(in_array($term->term_id, $multipleSelect2)){ ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>" selected><?php echo $term->name ?></option> 
    <?php } else{?>
         <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></option> 
    <?php }} ?>
</select>
```